# RecyclerViewAdapter not updating after an observable change

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, viewmodel

So I a fragment, which observes a list on a viewmodel, below is the code for that:

```
homeViewModel.getUrgentCharityList()
            .observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<Charity>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(List<Charity> charities) {
                    urgentCharityListRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

                    Log.d(TAG, String.format("Urgent charity list changed. %d items in list",
                            urgentCharityListRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()));
                }
            });
```

On observed change on the list, I just notify the RecyclerViewAdapter to refresh the RecyclerView.

Here is the code when I initialized the RecyclerView:

```
public void initializeCharityRecyclerView() {
    // Urgent charity list
    urgentCharityListRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_home_urgentCharityList);

    LinearLayoutManager urgentLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(),
            LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    urgentCharityListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(urgentLayoutManager);

    urgentCharityListRecyclerView.setAdapter(new CharityRecyclerViewAdapter(requireContext(),
            homeViewModel.getUrgentCharityList().getValue()));
}
```

The problem is that when the fragment is first created, the list data is fetched, but the RecyclerView doesn't refresh, weirdly when I change to another fragment then comes back the RecyclerView updates.

Below is my code for fetching the data from Firestore:

```
public void updateUrgentCharityList() {
    isUpdating.setValue(Boolean.TRUE);

    // Query all charities from Firestore
    charityRepository.getCurrentCharity().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                List<Charity> newUrgentCharityList = new ArrayList<Charity>();

                // Loop through query result
                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document: task.getResult()) {
                    // Convert query result into Charity object
                    Charity charity = document.toObject(Charity.class);
                    // Add Charity object into charityList
                    newUrgentCharityList.add(charity);

                    Log.d("HomeFragment", "Charity list query successful");
                }

                urgentCharityList.setValue(newUrgentCharityList);
            }
            else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Charity list query failed");
            }

            isUpdating.setValue(Boolean.FALSE);
        }
    });
}
```

I tried not notifying the adapter, but replacing the adapter with a new adapter it seems to work, but I think it's not a good way to replace the adapter for every change in the list.

The only problem that I could think of is because the data fetching is async, then that becomes a syncing issue? But why did replacing the adapter work then?

Can anybody explain the actual problem here?

Comment: show me the code where you are giving data(list) to the adapter in your activity/fragment.  As I see in your observer your not giving updated data to the adapter you are just only calling notifiyDataSetChanged.

Comment: @Yonatan When I initialized the recyclerview, I also set adapter 
`urgentCharityListRecyclerView.setAdapter(new CharityRecyclerViewAdapter(requireContext(),
                homeViewModel.getUrgentCharityList().getValue()));`

Comment: Which adapter did CharityRecylerViewAdapter extend ? RecyclerView.Adapter<> or ListAdapter

Comment: @Yonatan RecyclerView.Adapter<>
`public class CharityRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CharityRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>`

Answer (score 1):

Declare the adapter in class level

```
CharityRecyclerViewAdapter charityAdapter;
public void initializeCharityRecyclerView() {
// Urgent charity list
urgentCharityListRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_home_urgentCharityList);

LinearLayoutManager urgentLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(),
        LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
urgentCharityListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(urgentLayoutManager);
charityAdapter=new CharityRecyclerViewAdapter(requireContext(),homeViewModel.getUrgentCharityList().getValue());
urgentCharityListRecyclerView.setAdapter(charityAdapter);
}
```

then change the list visibility from private to public in your adapter class and update the list in the observer before calling notifyDatasetChanged

```
homeViewModel.getUrgentCharityList()
        .observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<Charity>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Charity> charities) {
                charityAdapter.charities=charities;
                charityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Log.d(TAG, String.format("Urgent charity list changed. %d items in list",
                        urgentCharityListRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()));
            }
        });
```

Comment: This does seem to work, but isn't it just like doing observe twice?

Comment: Not, it is observing once. you can omit a code that pass the data to the list in the adapter constructor, since we are setting the list in the observer.